# Canary build of the android emulator for AMD processor showing error

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

I am trying to run my app on canary build of the android emulator from android studio on AMD processor but I am getting the following error

```
1:47 PM Emulator: [2440]:INFO:android/android-emu/android/verified- 
boot/load_config.cpp:236:Verified boot params were not found.

1:47 PM Emulator: **

1:47 PM Emulator: ERROR:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/emu-master- 
dev/external/qemu/fpu/softfloat.c:486:round_canonical: code should not be 
reached

1:47 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 3
```

I got to know about the canary build of the android emulator for AMD processor from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=547DXRq8zAo). My virtual device' CPU/ABI is armeabi-v7a. I searched for what the 'exit code 3' for the emulator mean but I didn't get any solution. 
Can someone help me please!

Comment: Note https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113119775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the android emulator working today. 
I have done the instalation process for canary build of android studio from the beginning:

1. Enabled "Hyper-V" and "Windows Hypervisor Platform" in "Turn Windows features on or off" settings of Windows. This has been explained in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=547DXRq8zAo).

2. Downloaded the latest Canary build of Android studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/?utm_source=android-studio).

3. After downloading the zip file I followed the guidelines in [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview) under "Install alongside your stable version" heading. The guide lines are:

a. Unpack the ZIP file.

b. Rename the resulting folder to something unique like "Android Studio Preview."

c. Move it to a permanent location, such as next to your existing Android Studio install in C:\Program Files\Android.

d. Inside C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\bin\, launch studio64.exe (or if you're on a 32-bit machine, launch studio.exe).

4. After launching studio64.exe I got a pop-up message to update Android emulator. After the update I created a new virtual device with an image of x86 with android 9.0. I started the android emulator to test my app. Though I got the

```
Verified boot params were not found
```

popup error message initially, the emulator started functioning well.

Answer (score 0):

I am a very new Android developer and was until today having the same issue as yourself.  Here is how I got it to work (Please note I am also on an AMD system).

1. Make sure you have enabled Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform.  If you type "turn windows features on" in your run bar you should be able to locate it.  Also enable virtualisation in the Bios.  Mine comes under "SVD".

(Please note after this step I was still experiencing the problem but this is a pre-requisite).

2. Delete all devices from the AVD manager.
3. Install a new x86 device from the AVD manager.  What I did here was select a version down from the one I was previously getting issues on so Oreo from Pie.  When it asks to confirm if you want to wipe the user data please confirm positive.
4. Once setup, run the device from the AVD manager.  It may ask you if you wish to enable Instant Run.  I elected to disable this. (I had enabled it when I first was trying to run a device).
5. You will still receive the 1st error regarding no boot parameters but the emulated environment should load.  You can now run the APP and it should install the APK.  Previously due to the device not coming online properly, the APK would not install.  I can also now setup a device on Pie without experiencing the issue so I think it may have been the wiping of the previous data that helped.

I wish I could tell you WHY this worked for certain and previously it would not work, sadly I cannot but hopefully this will get you working.

Comment: Rezil, I haven't followed your steps but I am happy that android emulator is working and thank you for your response.